# I need to call a calculate function from my backend JS file to my frontend HTML file where it is a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My mentor told me I am supposed to do a $.post on my html file in order to get the answer my JS function will make for me. I cannot seem to get it right.
This is what my button looks like now:

```
<button style="margin-top:50px" type="button" id="calculate" onclick="addTip()",>Calculate!</button>
```

When I run it I get an error that says
currentTip.html:70 Uncaught ReferenceError: addTip is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
and  also Uncaught ReferenceError: addTip is not defined

My function is running properly but this is what it looks like in my js file

```
function calculateTip(billamt, serviceQualEl) {
  var roundedResult = (parseFloat(billamt) * parseFloat(serviceQualEl)).toFixed(2);
  return roundedResult;
}

function calculatebillamtEl1(billamtEl1, tipAmount) {
  return parseFloat(billamtEl1) + parseFloat(tipAmount);
}

function addTip() {
  var serviceQualEl = document.querySelector("#serviceQual").value;
  var billamtEl1 = document.querySelector("#billamt").value;

//sends tip amount with total to new page
function redirect(name, rating, tipAmount) {
  $.post("/api/serviceQual", { name, rating, tipAmount }).then(function () 
  { 
    window.location.replace("/previoustips") 
  });
}

         

I apologize I am not sure what to include in order to get proper help. Thank you.
```

Comment: Hi there kono and welcome to SO. If you are new here please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Read up on [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make your question as readable as possible. You've added a `react-fullstack` tag, but there seems to be no React code in either your code or question, though there is some jQuery. Please provide the correct tags to get help on the subjects that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Your missing a `}` after the addTip function, maybe that's it?

Comment: I removed it, Thank you for alerting me! I will check out the resource you have sent over.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, addTip() doesnt return or do anything?

Comment: Hey Jake, I apologize I did not include my whole function but I did check and the closing curly brace in my js is there. The JS is functioning for the mathmatics but I need help with bringing it to the front end. :)

Comment: addTip() comes back as not defined. I have tried defining it. I have tried the $.post my mentor told me and nothing has worked for me. I need the tip amount to be shown on the html page from the function I have in my js file.

Comment: add a jsfiddle of currentTip.html with js and html

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by jsfiddle and I am unaware of how that will help me.